# Bootstrap: Logo above navbar - In collapse mode, the main content does not move down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am trying to find a way to have a logo above my navbar. For the desktop version of my site, it is not a problem, but opening the page on a mobile device, makes some problems. As soon as the navbar is collapsed, toggling does not move the main content down. So the uncollapsed navbar overlaps some parts of the content.

This is my code:

```css
header[role="banner"] #logo-main {


}
#logo-main {


  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 37.5%;
  width: 340px;
  height:130px;

}

.headercontainer {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/418147/pexels-photo-418147.jpeg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 47.2%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /*  (827 / 1752 * 100) */
}

#navbar-primary.navbar-default {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 15%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
#navbar-primary.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar-primary.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

#navbar-primary.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color:black;
  padding-left: 85px;
  padding-right: 85px;
}

#navbar-primary.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color:black;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a > span {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover span {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  /*background-image: url("../images/blackdot.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headercontainer">
  <header role="banner">
  <img id="logo-main" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-white-social-media/32/logo_social_media_phone-2-512.png" alt="Spurwandel">
<nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="noleftpadding">Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html"><span class="noleftpadding">About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="coachings.html"><span class="noleftpadding">Coachings</span></a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="kontakt.html"><span class="noleftpadding">Kontakt</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header><!-- header role="banner" -->

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span>Main Content</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find an example here: https://www.bootply.com/jQG65nqmRE

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Lars

Comment: You need to use media queries and change the position because the logo is still at a 'position: absolute;'  when you're on a mobile device

Comment: After hours of frustrating trial and error, I don't get it... Do you perhaps have an example for me?